# Ruby File that Will Log All SQL INSERTs and SQL DELETEs (and only those commands)

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, sql-insert, sql-delete

I am working with a PostgreSQL database. I have written a .rb file I am using to manipulate data in the database. I want to be able to log all the SQL INSERTs  and DELETEs elicited by this file. How do I go about that?

Comment: It might help if you posted or Gist'ed the script here. Seems like if you're using the script to do inserts and deletes you should be able to log it easily.

Comment: A clean and easy solution is to create a custom db user for this script and then parse the db logs based on that user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of your script, create the needed temporary tables, and adds two triggers, one on insert, one on delete, and have them fire for each row accordingly. it also works with rules:

```
create temporary table foo_log_ins (like foo);

create rule log_foo_ins as
on insert to foo
do also
insert into foo_log select new.*;

create temporary table foo_log_del (like foo);

create rule log_foo_del as
on delete to foo
do also
insert into foo_log_del select old.*;
```